# When I hibernate, my computer no longer recognizes speakers, what should I do?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 19.04, pavucontrol

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 and have been experiencing sound issues.  Everytime I hibernate my computer, it no longer recognizes my internal speakers.  When I restart my computer, it recognizes them.  So I have to always shutdown computer after each session.  How can I fix this.

[only headphones show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHQ36.png)

[Only headphones show in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSrMl.png)

[Speakers show unplugged in pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfbkQ.png)

Again, this is only happening after I hibernate, everything is fine after I restart.